# Oracle 11g: Write a query that lists the highest earners for each department

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, subquery

This is a problem I've spent hours on now, and tried various different ways. *It HAS to use Subqueries*.

"Write a query that lists the highest earners for each department. Include the last_name, department_id, and the salary for each employee."

I've done a ton of subquery methods, and nothing works. I either get an error, or "No rows return". I'm assuming because one of the department_id is null, but even with NVL(department_id), I'm still having trouble. I tried splitting the table, and had no luck. Textbook's no help, my instructor is kind of useless, please... any help at all.

Here's a snapshot of the values, if that helps.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/bxtntlzqixdizzp/helpme.png?dl=0

Comment: It's a shame that it *has to* use subqueries, because that is not the best way to write the query.

Comment: I agree, there are better ways to do this without subqueries. I don't like this class at all. I don't mind SQL, it's just the way this class is (poorly) taught. I think they're getting paid by Oracle (who has a building right down the street from the school) to use their learning materials and tests, which aren't very effective in teaching you what you need to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rank the values within each department - then pull only the first place ranks in the outer query.

```
select a.last_name
,a.department_id
,a.salary
from (
  select last_name
  ,department_id
  ,salary
  ,rank() over (partition by department_id order by salary desc) as rnk
  from tablename
) a
where rnk=1
```

The partition groups all employees together who share the same department and should work regardless of the null value.

After grouping them - the order by tells that group to order on salary descending, and give a rank. You can run just the inner query to get an idea of what it does.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without displaying rank?

Comment: On the first line - instead of having [ select * from ( ] just define the column names again... in your case:

select a.last_name, a.department_id, a.salary from (

Comment: Thanks Neill. If my teacher doesn't like it or tries to mark me off because I didn't do it some godawful long way, I'll just file a complaint to the school about his course.

I really don't get why problems like this exist... Everything else, I had no issue with, but I was wrestling with this beast for over two hours before I caved in.